# how can I add a new count feature to the table I just generated in SQL?

Tags: sql

HERE is my sql code:

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(*), SUM(o.total_amt_usd) total_spent, 
     CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 200 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000 THEN 'top'
     WHEN COUNT(*) > 150 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 500000 THEN 'middle'
     ELSE 'low' END AS sales_rep_level
FROM orders o, accounts a, sales_reps s
WHERE o.account_id = a.id  AND s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

It generates an output like this:
[image]

My question is if I don't want to scroll down on my output page and manually count "how many 'top' sales_person in my query", can I add a line of code to achieve that? I know how to count(*) from the original tables of the database, not sure if I am able to count from the new columns I just generated.

Comment: you can count the new column generated. However, I am not sure what exactly do you need can you please share the expected results .

Comment: you can use subquery / CTE and join back the results to original table

Comment: @trillion  I want to add a column of count(sales_rep_level) in my output. As you see there are 50 sales representatives, 11 are top sales,  maybe 20 are middle sales... I want to have an idea how many top sales in the company.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @Yi.D chekc the solution below but it is not that clean

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as a subquery and add a window function:

```
SELECT name,
       count,
       total_spent,
       sales_rep_level,
       count(*) OVER () AS num_rows
FROM (SELECT s.name,
             COUNT(*) AS count,
             SUM(o.total_amt_usd) total_spent, 
             CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 200 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000
                  THEN 'top'
                  WHEN COUNT(*) > 150 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 500000
                  THEN 'middle'
                  ELSE 'low'
             END AS sales_rep_level
      FROM orders o, accounts a, sales_reps s
      WHERE o.account_id = a.id  AND s.id = a.sales_rep_id
      GROUP BY 1) AS subq
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I just put your code back, and the output for the column 'num_rows' shows all the numbers of '50'. I want to add a column of count(sales_rep_level), showing top sales count as 11, and middle sales as 20+ .

Comment: How can one column show two values? Or do you want to add two columns, one that has the count of "top" `sales_rep_level` and one for the "middle"?

Comment: @ Laurenz Albe, I just realized I cannot put name, sales_rep_level and count(*) at the same time expecting to count and group by sales_rep_level. I have to remove the 'name' column. It is adding confusion to the database of which column it needs to count.  Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In short if a row has a specific category then the total number of rows for that category will show up but for the other categories it will not show.
For example a row with TOP LEVEL will show count_total as a total number of top level in entire data. While a row with midd level will only show total number of mid level in entire data

```
with main_data as (

SELECT s.name, COUNT(*), SUM(o.total_amt_usd) total_spent, 
     CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 200 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000 THEN 'top'
     WHEN COUNT(*) > 150 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 500000 THEN 'middle'
     ELSE 'low' END AS sales_rep_level
FROM orders o, accounts a, sales_reps s
WHERE o.account_id = a.id  AND s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC

)

Count_based_on_levels as (

select 
*,
COUNT(*)
over(partition by sales_rep_level) as count_total

from main_data


-- or just do this in new CTE 

select

sales_rep_level,
count(*) 
from table
group by 1

-- even if you would join this back then based on the data that you sent 
-- you will be able to only join it using sales_rep_level which will again
-- produce the same results i.e showing values for top only when the top 
-- sales_rep_level row is there
```

Answer (score 0):

Push your current query into a sub-query then use the Windowed version of count. Also learn to newer (only 30 years old) standard join syntax.

```
select name, total_spent, sales_rep_level
     , count(*) over (partition by sales_rep_level) sales_reps_in_level
 
from (select s.name, count(*), sum(o.total_amt_usd) total_spent, 
            case when count(*) > 200 or sum(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000 then 'top'
                 when count(*) > 150 or sum(o.total_amt_usd) > 500000 then 'middle'
                 else 'low' 
            end as sales_rep_level
       from orders o 
       join accounts a on ( o.account_id = a.id )
       join sales_reps s on ( s.id = a.sales_rep_id)
       group by 1
      ) s
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't know it was an old coding style to write"join". I thought this was a cleaner coding(less wording). At first, I didn't like to write the new way, which is to write many "Join" if I need to link many tables together.

Comment: True  the old syntax fewer words, but that is NOT always a improvement (and try an outer join). The JOIN syntax is much easier to clearly see what the query is doing and much much harder to omit a condition. Each of these on there own surpasses fewer words, together no contest.  Unfortunately the documentation still has the old format. (I think it is updated in version 14).

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with a count, all rows will have the same value = number of top in the  result.

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(*), SUM(o.total_amt_usd) total_spent, 
     CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 200 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000 THEN 'top'
     WHEN COUNT(*) > 150 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 500000 THEN 'middle'
     ELSE 'low' END AS sales_rep_level,
     SUM (COUNT(*) > 200 OR SUM(o.total_amt_usd) > 750000) OVER() nmbr_of_tops
FROM orders o, accounts a, sales_reps s
WHERE o.account_id = a.id  AND s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Comment: THank you. Got it.